# Below query is not working in 10g (10.2.0.4) showing ORA-00904: "A","TEMP_APPL_ID" : invalid identifier

Tags: oracle

i have facing this issue in Oracle 10g 10.2.0.4 server, while executing below query its showing error **ORA-00904: "A","TEMP_APPL_ID" : invalid identifier**

```
Update PO_AGENCY_TEMP a  set 
    (massag_value)=(
       SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(str,'\d+',1,1) NUM
        FROM
         (SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(unit_code,'([A-Z]+-\d+-[A-Z]+)','',4,4,'i') str
         FROM PO_AGENCY_TEMP b where a.temp_appl_id = b.temp_appl_id));
```

Whereas this query execute properly in oracle **10g 10.2.0.2** server.

Please help.

Atanu Maity

Answer (score 3):

You may try this:

```
Update PO_AGENCY_TEMP a 
   set massag_value=(SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(REGEXP_REPLACE(unit_code,'([A-Z]+-\d+-[A-Z]+)','',4,4,'i'),'\d+',1,1) num
         FROM PO_AGENCY_TEMP b where a.temp_appl_id = b.temp_appl_id);
```

As I know there is a restriction on the max level of nested subqueries where you can use a column from a parent query. It equals to 1 in Oracle.

However the situation is really strange:

1) It didn't work in Oracle 9i:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96540/queries8.htm

> Oracle performs a correlated subquery when **the subquery references a
>   column from a table referred to in the parent statement**. A correlated
>   subquery is evaluated once for each row processed by the parent
>   statement. The parent statement can be a SELECT, UPDATE, or DELETE
>   statement.

2) Then it started to work in Oracle 10g:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/server.101/b10759/queries007.htm

> Oracle performs a correlated subquery when a nested subquery
>   references a column from a table referred to a parent statement **any
>   number of levels** above the subquery. The parent statement can be a
>   SELECT, UPDATE, or DELETE statement in which the subquery is nested. A
>   correlated subquery is evaluated once for each row processed by the
>   parent statement. Oracle resolves unqualified columns in the subquery
>   by looking in the tables named in the subquery and then in the tables
>   named in the parent statement.

3) Oracle 11g states the same as Oracle 10g:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/queries007.htm#SQLRF52340

However people say that it doesn't work:
https://community.oracle.com/message/3405285
https://community.oracle.com/thread/380604

I tried a "2-level deep" correlated subquery in Oracle 10g/11g without success. But I cannot find any "solid" explanation of this.